# $u_n^2$ converges and $u_n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have an example of "**sequence $u_n^2$ converges and $u_n$ diverges**":

$\forall (a,b,n)\in \mathbb R^*\times \{2k+1,\forall k\in\mathbb Z\} \times\mathbb N$,

$u_n=a(-1)^{bn}$

Is there other examples of such sequence or is this the unique form.

Note: $a$ can also be replaced by a converging sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that if $u_n^2$ converges, then $|u_n|$ converges as well. $u_n$ can and will diverge if the limit is not zero and the sign of $u_n$ changes infinitely often.

Or the other way round, take any sequence $u_n$ with a limit that is not 0, then change the sign infinitely often. Say change the sign if n is the 100th power of a prime.

Answer (score 1):

There’s lots of possibilities. For example $1,1,-1,1,1,-1,…$ and your $u_n+1/n^2$.